# My node version of project is v14 and it is now deprecated. If I upgrade my machine node to v18 and run npm install, it gives me this error

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, node-modules, npm-install, nvm

I tried using v14 it gave me this error.
ERR: Your Node.js version is v14.17.4. Node.js 14 reached end-of-life on 2023-04-30 and is no longer supported. Please update to the latest Node LTS version.
And when I update to latest it gave some hash error. What should I do now?

Comment: It's not possible for us to know what's in your project and what exactly is being installed by `npm install`.  You'll have to figure out those details.